# Confusion regarding “to doing something” vs. “to do something”

Tags: word-choice

I am always confused with the form of “to doing something”, *e.g.:*

> I admitted to **doing** something.

*vs.:*

> I admitted to **do** something.

Comment: Many people are confused with stuff like this. The problem is thinking of _to doing_ as being a unit. _To_ and _doing_ are just two words that might come together accidentally, whereas _to do_ is a unit, a **constituent**, an infinitive verb with an infinitive complementizer _to_

Comment: Thank you for your comment.What is the difference between these two expressions. especially the meaning. How should I use "to doing something" in my writing.

Comment: You shouldn't use it; it's not an expression. That's what I just said.

Comment: @John Lawler, so in the phase, "I admitted to doing x," does the word "doing" constitute a gerund?

Comment: _Doing x_ constitutes a gerund clause (or at least the verb phrase of it -- the subject of _doing_ is also the subject of _admitted_, so it's deleted by A-Equi. _Admitted to_ is the main verb, and the _to_ is required for any object, whether it's a gerund or a noun or a pronoun; the bracketing is [[admitted to] [doing x]]. With an infinitive _want to do x_, the bracketing is [want [to [do x]]].

Comment: @JohnLawler why don't you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The question's title is in so far incorrectly phrased as the choice between the gerund "doing" and the infinitive "to do" is based on which word is preceding.

For instance, the fixed expression "to look forward to" is followed by a gerund while the verb "to agree" is followed by an infinitive.

Examples:

> I am looking forward to hearing from you.
>   She agreed to let me go early.

To make it worse, there are verbs which are followed by both gerund and infinitive; and sometimes, they mean pretty much the same thing and in other cases, they are totally different in meaning.

The disappointing truth is that you'll have to learn and remember it for every verb. Luckily, most times a dictionary will tell you which to use. In case of "to [admit](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/admit) to something" (where *something* is your action you've admitted to) the expression is followed by gerund.

> She admits to being strict with her children.

Answer (score -2):

> I admit to doing something.
>
> I admit to do something.

Both the sentences are correct. But I think the first one is used more often than the second one. Actually the second one is very rare, and old fashioned.

As others have already mentioned, it all depends on the whether the verb is followed by gerund or infinitive.

**Example -**

> I look forward **to playing** on our home ground.

This is the correct sentence, but using ***to play*** here, instead ***to playing*** is considered wrong or incorrect.

But what if the verb is neutral, I mean where the verb can take both the form? Then, how to decide when to use ***to + verb*** and when to use ***to + verb + ing***?

**There is a simple rule** -

Write the sentence till you reach ***to***, and then omit the rest part for the time being. Replace the rest part with a noun. If this make sense and seems correct, you can use ***to + verb + ing*** form, otherwise stick to infinitive form ***to + verb***

**Example -**

Consider the sentence -

1. He loves to play football.
2. He loves to playing football.

Following the above rule, write till ***to***

He loves to Football.

It doesn't convey the meaning properly. So we can't use ***to + verb + ing*** form. And hence only sentence #1 is correct.

Now consider this -

1. He reached closer to finishing the job.

Following the rule, rewrite the sentence till ***to***

He reached closer to THE DEADLINE (A Noun). This makes sense, and so we can use ***to +  verb + ing*** form, as well as the base infinitive form **to + verb*** form.

Does this answer make sense?

Comment: I haven't read this answer beyond the first sentence *("Both the sentence is correct")*. That sentence is both untrue and ungrammatical, which is quite enough to justify my downvote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually there are instances where the second sentence are used. But they are very rare, and from Ngram it shows that it actually was in use in the past. So I don't see any point to declare it to be incorrect. But it's true enough that we should avoid this construction.

Comment: If you go back a couple of centuries and more, there *was* a time when the meaning and syntax of ***admit*** could in some contexts correspond to today's ***permit***. But it was never common even then, and it's certainly of no relevance to anyone wishing to learn *current* English.

Answer (score -3):

As per my understanding;

"I admitted to doing something." : This is wrong.

Doing something means you are currently working on it. You are combining Simple Past + present continues that gives wrong meaning.

"I admitted to do something." : This is correct.
This is a simple past form and this is correct. This means you you are describing thing happened in the past.

Thanks
Emil

Comment: _I admitted to doing something_ is __correct__, and _I admitted to do something_ is __incorrect__, in AusE, BrE, AmE, and NZE.