# Confusion regarding "confusion of"

Tags: grammaticality

I have a question regarding the title of this question: [Confusion regarding “to doing something” vs. “to do something”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23260/confusion-of-to-doing-something-with-to-do-something).

My initial thought as an ESL student was to use "Confusion about" instead of "confusion of". It doesn't make sense to use confusion of. Thus, I used "confusion regarding" in my title to avoid this error.

When should I use "of" vs "about" ?

**UPDATE:** Another example:

- I'm still confused of vs I'm still confused about
- I'm thinking of you vs I'm thinking about you

**UPDATE 2:** The question I have linked has been edited. Nonetheless, I have added more examples in my question which I hope someone can use to help me clear the confusion.

Answer (score 7):

This goes back to two related but very different meanings of the verb *confuse*

- One meaning of *confuse* takes **two** objects, call them A and B. To *confuse A and B* means to **“mix them up”**, to mistake A for B and B for A.

  > I always confuse Amy and her sister Barbara. Which is the one with green eyes?

  In this sense we also say *confuse A **with** B*.

  > I think you are confusing Argentina with Brazil. They speak Spanish in Argentina, but Portuguese in Brazil.

  When you turn *confuse* into the noun *confusion*, you should use ***of*** to designate its two objects.

  > My confusion ***of*** Amy and Barbara got me in big trouble when I brought Amy a present on Barbara’s birthday.
- The other meaning of *confuse* is to **“bewilder”** or **“puzzle”** someone—usually a person, but an animal can be confused as well.

  > Carol confuses me. I can never tell whether she’s really angry or just joking.
  >
  > His sudden shout confused the bear, which turned to see where the sound came from.

  When you say “I am confused”, you are using this sense in the passive voice: something *confuses* you. We have two ways of designating that ‘something’: either with ***by*** or with ***about***.

  - Use ***by*** when you are talking about something which you feel is in some way responsible for your confusion, something which ‘actively’ confuses you: a person for instance, or a text.

  > > I am confused ***by*** this passage in *Macbeth*. I can’t make out what he is saying.

  - Use ***about*** when you feel that it is you or your misunderstanding which is responsible for the confusion.

  > > I am confused **about** when to use *to doing*.

  But we never use ***of*** with *confuse* or *confusion* in this sense:

  > > <sup>∗</sup> I am confused of when to use *to doing*.

When you use the noun *confusion* on ELL, chances are that you are confused ***about*** something. Occasionally you will be asking how to avoid confusion ***of*** one thing with another. And every once in a while an Answerer will point out that confusion is created ***by*** a speaker or writer or teacher:

> I cannot blame you for being confused ***by*** this definition of the past perfect. It is entirely wrong. Throw that book away. Read what FumbleFingers says instead.

---

ADDED:
The question you have added addresses a different verb, which uses prepositions quite differently. (This is usually the case; you can almost never generalize from the use of a preposition in one context to its use in other contexts.)

*Think*, again, has two different meanings. One is to “examine a matter mentally”; in this sense, the matter you are examining may be expressed with either ***of*** or ***about***.

> I’m thinking ***of*** you all the time.
>   I’m thinking ***about*** you all the time. ... *these two mean the same thing.*

The other meaning of *think* is to “hold an opinion concerning something”. In a question, we use either ***about*** or ***of*** to designate the something:

> What do you think of *The Fountainhead*?
>   What do you think about *The Fountainhead*?

But in statements we use ***of***, complemented by an ***as*** phrase; or  no preposition complemented by a nominal or adjective phrase; or a full clause, finite or non-finite. We never use *about*.

> <sup>ok</sup>I think of it as one of the seminal works of modern philosophy. (*a very rare use*)
>   <sup>ok</sup>I think it pretentious and jejune.  (*an occasional use*)
>   <sup>ok</sup>I think it is preposterous rubbish. (*the most common use*)
>   <sup>ok</sup>I think it to be repulsive and unreadable.  (*a rare use*)
>   <sup>∗</sup>  I think about it a vile threat to our democratic institutions. (*an unacceptable use*)

---

<sup>∗</sup>  *marks a usage as unacceptable*